# PDF file not opening in release version of android in flutter

Tags: android, api, flutter, flutter-dependencies

In Android Studio Emulator, the pdf file is opening but when I release its .apk file and install it on my phone, pdf file does not open. I used flutter_pdfview package to load pdf file.

This is where the page is shown.

```
import 'package:darpandentalhome/services/api_for_report.dart';
import 'package:darpandentalhome/shared/loading.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Report extends StatefulWidget {

  final String url;

  Report({this.url});

  @override
  _ReportState createState() => _ReportState();
}

class _ReportState extends State<Report> {

  String path;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    ApiService(pdfURL: widget.url).loadPDF().then((value){
      setState(() {
        path=value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
            'Report',
          style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
            )
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,color: Colors.black,),
          onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff9f9f9),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfff9f9f9),
      body: path != null ? Container(
        child: PDFView(
          filePath: path,
        ),
      ) : Loading(),
      floatingActionButton: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.refresh,size: 30,),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            path = null;
            ApiService(pdfURL: widget.url).loadPDF().then((value){
              setState(() {
                path=value;
              });
            });
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is for the HTTP API service for fetching pdf file from HTTP URL.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class ApiService{

  final String pdfURL;

  ApiService({this.pdfURL});

  Future<String> loadPDF() async {
    var response = await http.get(pdfURL);
    var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = File(dir.path + "/data.pdf");
    await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes, flush: true);
    return file.path;
  }

}
```

I thought it was a permission issue of the phone then I used storage permission in AndroidManifest file then manually allowed this permission on my phone but it also didn't work.
What is the problem here?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved after giving internet permission to the app since the http api need to fetch data from internet.

Answer (score 2):

it's because difference between android version
if your android version is 29 use this code in your manifest 
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: there is no option for the code you suggested. When I copy/paste you code then it says unknown attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to fix:

```
    1. Add proguard-rules.pro in android/app folder file if its not already there

    2. Inside of the proguard-rules.pro file put this:
        -keep class com.shockwave.**
        -keepclassmembers class com.shockwave.** { *; }
        
    3.In app/build.gradle add this:

       buildTypes{
             release{
                shrinkResources true
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```